# JOLT shift transformation: collect all the items from all the levels without knowing how many levels

Tags: java, json, tree, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON using Jolt transformation looking for some input here.
I am trying to get all the items from all the levels into an array.

**My goal is to get an array that contains all the items without knowing how many levels I have in the json.**

Here is my input and expected output:

if I've 3 levels:

*Input*:

```json
{
  "id": 11,
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "11_1",
      "item": [
        {
          "id": "11_1_1",
          "item": [
            {
              "id": "11_1_1_1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "11_1_2",
          "item": [
            {
              "id": "11_1_2_1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Expected output*:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "11_1"
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_1"
  },
    {
    "id": "11_1_1_1"
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_2"
  },
    {
    "id": "11_1_2_1"
  }
]
```

if I've 2 levels:

*Input*:

```json
{
  "id": 11,
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "11_1",
      "item": [
        {
          "id": "11_1_1"
        },
        {
          "id": "11_1_2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Expected output*:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "11_1"
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_1"
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_2"
  }
]
```

I tried to write something like:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {   //to cover the second level
        "*": "item"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {    //to cover the 3td level
          "item": {
            "*": "item"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

The result was null, if I run each transformation separately, I get results when applicable
Can you please help me to write a simple spec that will do this?

Comment: You may consider another library [Josson](https://github.com/octomix/josson). The transformation query for this task is `item.cumulateCollect(field(item:), item)`

Comment: @RaymondChoi but we need to write the transformation in a Json and not in a code

Comment: Actually, _Josson_ transform and query JSON by pure text query statement, not by Java code. I will add an answer to show the solution for unlimited level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the inputs have at most 3 levels as in your case, then use this spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "id": "&",
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "id": "&",
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "id": "&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": {
        "*": "[#1].&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to handle the both cases using only this one. If one more level is needed as well, then add

```json
,
"item": {
  "*": {
    "id": "&"
  }
}
```

just after the inner most

```json
"id": "&"
```

**Edit** : If you have some other attributes than `id` as lately commented like in the below input sample

```json
{
  "id": 11,
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "11_1",
      "quantity": 1,
      "action": "add",
      "state": "x",
      "item": [
        {
          "id": "11_1_1",
          "quantity": 2,
          "action": "drop",
          "state": "y"
        },
        {
          "id": "11_1_2",
          "quantity": 3,
          "action": "modify",
          "state": "z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

than just a little modification would handle your new case :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&",
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&",
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#1].&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which would generate :

```json
[
  {
    "id": "11_1",
    "quantity": 1,
    "action": "add",
    "state": "x"
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_1",
    "quantity": 2,
    "action": "drop",
    "state": "y"
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_2",
    "quantity": 3,
    "action": "modify",
    "state": "z"
  }
]
```

Comment: if I want to get all the object of each item (in case I've another properties in addition to the id)
{
  "item": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "quantity": 1,
      "action": "add",
      "state": "x"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "action": "add",
      "state": "x"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: then just convert the pieces `"id": "&"` to `"*": "&"` within the first, and `"spec": { "id": {...` to `"spec": { "*": {...` within the second spec @Michal

Comment: thanks, I have a slightly more complex case, I will write a new question.

Comment: The new Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74207632/jolt-shift-transformation-collect-all-the-items-from-all-the-levels-without-kno

Answer (score 0):

Solution for unlimited levels using library *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"id\": 11," +
    "  \"item\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"id\": \"11_1\"," +
    "      \"quantity\": 1," +
    "      \"action\": \"add\"," +
    "      \"state\": \"x\"," +
    "      \"item\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "          \"id\": \"11_1_1\"," +
    "          \"quantity\": 2," +
    "          \"action\": \"drop\"," +
    "          \"state\": \"y\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "          \"id\": \"11_1_2\"," +
    "          \"quantity\": 3," +
    "          \"action\": \"modify\"," +
    "          \"state\": \"z\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      ]" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("item.cumulateCollect(field(item:), item)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Statement `field(item:)` removes field `item` from the current object.
The 2nd argument of `cumulateCollect()` means the next level. In this case is `item`.

**Output**

```
[ {
  "id" : "11_1",
  "quantity" : 1,
  "action" : "add",
  "state" : "x"
}, {
  "id" : "11_1_1",
  "quantity" : 2,
  "action" : "drop",
  "state" : "y"
}, {
  "id" : "11_1_2",
  "quantity" : 3,
  "action" : "modify",
  "state" : "z"
} ]
```