# JOLT shift transformation: collect the items from all the levels without knowing how many levels when there are multiple properties

Tags: java, json, tree, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON using Jolt transformation looking for some input here.
I am trying to get the items from all the levels into an one array.
**My goal is to get an array that contains a part of the items without knowing how many levels I have in the json.**

Here is my input and expected output:

*Input*:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "1_1",
      "item": [
        {
          "id": "1_1_2",
          "foo": [
            {
              "nn": "cc",
              "vvv": "2022-08-30T06:44:24.943Z",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "ss",
              "vvv": "rr",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "ii",
              "vvv": "rr",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "uu",
              "vvv": "kk",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "pp",
              "vvv": "aaa",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "bb",
              "vvv": "tt",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "ff",
              "vvv": "tt",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "ff",
              "vvv": "tt",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "pp",
              "vvv": "yy",
              "mmm": "oo"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "foo": [
        {
          "nn": "cc",
          "vvv": "ww",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "ss",
          "vvv": "rr",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "ii",
          "vvv": "rr",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "uu",
          "vvv": "kk",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "pp",
          "vvv": "aaa",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "bb",
          "vvv": "tt",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "d",
          "vvv": "tt",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "pp",
          "vvv": "yy",
          "mmm": "oo"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1_2",
      "item": [
        {
          "id": "1_2_1",
          "foo": [
            {
              "nn": "cc",
              "vvv": "ww",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "ss",
              "vvv": "rr",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "ii",
              "vvv": "rr",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "uu",
              "vvv": "kk",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "pp",
              "vvv": "aaa",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "bb",
              "vvv": "tt",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "bb_ee4d6bf4-1081-468a-b7b1-5445333dfab2",
              "vvv": "tt",
              "mmm": "oo"
            },
            {
              "nn": "pp",
              "vvv": "yy",
              "mmm": "oo"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "foo": [
        {
          "nn": "cc",
          "vvv": "ww",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "ss",
          "vvv": "rr",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "ii",
          "vvv": "rr",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "uu",
          "vvv": "kk",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "pp",
          "vvv": "aaa",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "bb",
          "vvv": "tt",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "d",
          "vvv": "tt",
          "mmm": "oo"
        },
        {
          "nn": "pp",
          "vvv": "yy",
          "mmm": "oo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Expected output*:

```json
[
  {
    "foo": [
      {
        "nn": "cc",
        "vvv": "ww",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ss",
        "vvv": "rr",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ii",
        "vvv": "rr",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "uu",
        "vvv": "kk",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "pp",
        "vvv": "aaa",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "bb",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "d",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "pp",
        "vvv": "yy",
        "mmm": "oo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "foo": [
      {
        "nn": "cc",
        "vvv": "2022-08-30T06:44:24.943Z",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ss",
        "vvv": "rr",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ii",
        "vvv": "rr",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "uu",
        "vvv": "kk",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "pp",
        "vvv": "aaa",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "bb",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ff",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ff",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "pp",
        "vvv": "yy",
        "mmm": "oo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "foo": [
      {
        "nn": "cc",
        "vvv": "ww",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ss",
        "vvv": "rr",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ii",
        "vvv": "rr",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "uu",
        "vvv": "kk",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "pp",
        "vvv": "aaa",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "bb",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "d",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "pp",
        "vvv": "yy",
        "mmm": "oo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "foo": [
      {
        "nn": "cc",
        "vvv": "ww",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ss",
        "vvv": "rr",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "ii",
        "vvv": "rr",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "uu",
        "vvv": "kk",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "pp",
        "vvv": "aaa",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "bb",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "bb_ee4d6bf4-1081-468a-b7b1-5445333dfab2",
        "vvv": "tt",
        "mmm": "oo"
      },
      {
        "nn": "pp",
        "vvv": "yy",
        "mmm": "oo"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can you please told me how to do it right?

Comment: Hi Michal, I've realised that the answer will be similar to the previous one, just replace the asterisks(keys) on the line 7,10,13 with `foo`es...

Comment: eg. you can use this : `[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "foo": "@(1,id).&",
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "foo": "@(1,id).&",
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "foo": "@(1,id).&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
`

Comment: Many many thanks!!!, I've another little Q please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74254469/jolt-shift-transformation-collect-the-items-from-all-the-levels-without-knowing hope its ok...

Comment: little more issue regarding this Q plz: if I want to change the name of one property in foo object  for exa: from "nn" to "kk" how should I do it in the spec above? onle with 1 or 2 specs not more... thanks ahead!!

Comment: Can you please edit what exactly you want on this question please ?

Comment: use the same input and the output is also the same but the property "nn" in the "foo" will be "kk" in the new output, should I open a new Q?

Comment: No, not need to opn a new question, just better to edit such details those you mentioned. I'll be looking at it when I'm available.

Comment: ok, I open a new one a little bit diff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74263027/jolt-shift-transformation-collect-the-items-from-all-the-levels-and-change-the