# JOLT shift transformation: collect the items from all the levels and change the property name

Tags: java, json, tree, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON using Jolt transformation looking for some input here.
I am trying to get a part of the items into an one array.
**My goal is to get an array that contains a part of the items.**

Here is my input and expected output:

*Input*:

```json
{
  "item": [
    {
      "ac": "i",
      "id": "c5b9e16076fe4faaaace5c7d0cbe0d9b",
      "foo": {
        "id": "c5b9e16076fe4faaaace5c7d0cbe0d9b",
        "nn": "de38c8a2e6a844d1a9dd7a573eedee15"
      },
      "item": [
        {
          "ac": "y",
          "id": "c5b9e16076fe4faaaace5c7d0cbe0d9b",
          "foo": {
            "id": "c5b9e16076fe4faaaace5c7d0cbe0d9b",
            "nn": "b1754500dde646f1af495814fcd2d65e"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "r",
          "ac": "ac",
          "foo": {
            "id": "c5b9e16076fe4faaaace5c7d0cbe0d9b",
            "nn": "bfb5550a6d754892b313ab9dd8604725"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Expected output*:

```json
[
  {
    "ac": "y",
    "foo": {
      "nn": [
        "b1754500dde646f1af495814fcd2d65e"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "ac": "i",
    "foo": {
      "nn": "de38c8a2e6a844d1a9dd7a573eedee15"
    }
  },
  {
    "ac": "ac",
    "foo": {
      "nn": "bfb5550a6d754892b313ab9dd8604725"
    }
  }
]
```

*My spec*:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "ac": "[&1].ac",
                  "foo": {
                    "nn": "[&2].foo.&"
                  }
                }
              },
              "ac": "[&1].ac",
              "foo": {
                "nn": "[&2].foo.&"
              }
            }
          },
          "ac": "[&1].ac",
          "foo": {
            "nn": "[&2].foo.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The result isn't what I expected, I got:
*My output*:

```json
[ {
  "ac" : [ "y", "i" ],
  "foo" : {
    "nn" : [ "b1754500dde646f1af495814fcd2d65e", "de38c8a2e6a844d1a9dd7a573eedee15" ]
  }
}, {
  "ac" : "ac",
  "foo" : {
    "nn" : "bfb5550a6d754892b313ab9dd8604725"
  }
} ]
```

a list of the ac and list of the KK not each properties of item together in a one list of items

Can you please told me how to do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to determine the valid separation patterns to construct the independent objects; this case I've used `"ac": "@(1,id).&1.&"` and `"nn": "@(3,id).&3.foo.KK"` (*as staying two levels inner*) patterns for each construction model such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "ac": "@(1,id).&1.&",
                  "foo": {
                    "*": {
                      "nn": "@(3,id).&3.foo.KK"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "ac": "@(1,id).&1.&",
              "foo": {
                "*": {
                  "nn": "@(3,id).&3.foo.KK"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "ac": "@(1,id).&1.&",
          "foo": {
            "*": {
              "nn": "@(3,id).&3.foo.KK"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // get rid of separator labels of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** (*based on the edited question*) : You can use the following spec for the new case

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "ac": "@(1,ac).&",
                  "foo": {
                    "nn": "@(2,ac).&1[#1].&"
                  }
                }
              },
              "ac": "@(1,ac).&",
              "foo": {
                "nn": "@(2,ac).&1[#1].&"
              }
            }
          },
          "ac": "@(1,ac).&",
          "foo": {
            "nn": "@(2,ac).&1[#1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of separator labels of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks, but oopssss, I just change the Q a little bit

Comment: Sorry and many thanks, I tried your spec on my real input and I got only the "ac" and not the value of the foo, maybe its because in my real input I've another properties under the foo in addition the "id" and "nn" , do u think its related?

Comment: yes this is a typo, cz I chnaged my real issue to be a small and simple (relatively)
what should I change if I've another properties in foo?

Comment: I'm fixing the Q

Comment: fixed, BTW in this Q input I've only 3 items but in my real data I've more items and more levels, thanks ahead!

Comment: thanks, I checked it on my real input and I got list of "ac" and list of "nn" under the foo, not each "ac" with his "nn" into a list, do u know why?

Comment: I abled to fix it by changed "nn": "@(2,ac).&1[#1].&" to "nn": "@(2,id).&1[#1].&" from "ac" to "id"

Comment: if I want that foo wont contains list in the output "foo" : { ["nn" : "bfb5550a6d754892b313ab9dd8604725"] } , only   "foo" : { "nn" : "bfb5550a6d754892b313ab9dd8604725" } what should I do?

Comment: just remove those three `[#1]` @Michal

Comment: another Q plz: if I want that the object in the input will be like: 
{
  "ac" : "ac",
    "nn" : "bfb5550a6d754892b313ab9dd8604725"
  } without the "foo" level, what should I change in the spec?

Comment: Then use `"nn": "@(2,ac).&"` for each occurences of pairs with `nn` key @Michal

Comment: more Q plz: if I want to wrap all the output with another level for exa "items", how should I do that?

Comment: managed, just change the second spec to:   {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "items"
    }
  }